# Is the order of comparisant important in a join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I usually code a join query as follows:

```
Select 'field' from 'table' join 'references' on 'table'.'id' = 'references'.'reference'
```

Now suddenly I wondered, does the order in which you do `on 'table'.'id' = 'references'.'reference'` have an impact on execution speed or not?

I mainly use sqlserver, mysql and sqlite and I can imagine there might be different implementations in those three if there is a difference at all.

So basically it boils down to:

is `on 'table'.'id' = 'references'.'reference'` different from `on 'references'.'reference' = 'table'.'id'`

This question is purely out of curiosity, I'd like to know how it is treated so I can understand it better.

Comment: No, it's the difference between `x*y` vs `y*x`, i.e. no difference at all. By convention, we tend to say 'FROM x JOIN y ON y.id = x.id' because it sounds more natural to express it that way, but that's all.

Comment: These day Databases use COST BASED MODEL so both are same http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-cost-based-optimization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in execution if you write the SQL-Statement

```
Select 'field' 
from 'table' 
join 'references' 
on 'table'.'id' = 'references'.'reference'
```

or

```
Select 'field' 
from 'table' 
join 'references' 
on 'references'.'reference' = 'table'.'id'
```

You also could write it as a cross join (only possible for inner joins)

```
Select 'field' 
from 'table' 
cross join 'references' 
where 'table'.'id' = 'references'.'reference'
```

I would'n use the third example for doing inner joins. But it explains that it makes no difference for equality joins if you think about the logical expression. 
Sure, if you have the following comparison in the on-cluase  `x > y`  then you have to change the operator to `y < x`

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in that order.
Join condition `ON (..here..)` is just а logical expression, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

`'table'.'id' = 'references'.'reference'` is the same as `'references'.'reference' = 'table'.'id'` But regarding ordering you should always use order by clause for safe side.

As per my experience I can say about mysql that it uses default ordering based on timestamp means if you don't specify order by in your query then it will first show which row first created and so on...

Note: If you are using group by clause then it will use ordering as mentioned fields in group by.

Comment: See the indented paragraph at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html. If you care about the order, always include an order by clause. If your version of MySQL considers it unnecessary, it will be optimised away.

Comment: @Strawberry: I completely agree with you, same I mentioned in my post that always use order by to make sure correct ordering but yes I have tested it several times that if we don't use order by then mysql provide results order based on row creation....but mysql documentation does not commit that always this will be the case...